# Better understand of sockt - is it ok to use the same raw socket to send data from different interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I read [raw socket tutorial](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html)  in order to implement my own bridge (i capture package from one side and send them to the other interface by raw socket). I am coming from Java world, so low level programming is strange to me, so forgive me for my ignorance.

I implement a bridge, so I need to send traffic from A to interface B and vice versa.
I created a single raw socket and I used it to send data to both servers by 2 different interfaces.is there any reason to why not use the same socket in order to send from interface A or B? I am asking if it's a good practice? problems and etc

It will be great if you can clarify to me how socket is not binded to a physical interface in the underline. this is the reason that it seems strange to me that the same raw socket use to send data for different interfaces.

Comment: There are several questions here, one in your title and one or two more in your question. Are they related? Which are you asking?

Comment: For me they are the same. The bottom line is it ok to use the same socket ?

Comment: They're not the same to me. One is about how to bind a socket, the other is about how many sockets. Two questions -> two threads.

Comment: I will clarify the question . Thank you.

Comment: What does 'in the underline' mean?

Comment: underline - i mean like that you have layers and at the end you have physical layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem to use the same raw socket for two different interfaces. the use in the specific interface is done when you call to send.